# Creating permutations of the column based on same column value Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

I am trying to create a cross join in order to get this result. The goal is to get permutations of a column based on a same value in the same table . This is the input :

| Id | name | desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | App |
| 1 | apple | Aps |
| 2 | apple | Apl |
| 2 | apple | Ale |
| 2 | apple | Apls |
| 3 | orange | orng |

Now this the result I want only name is Similar then add it.

| Id | name | desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | App |
| 1 | apple | Aps |
| 1 | apple | Apl |
| 1 | apple | Ale |
| 1 | apple | Apls |
| 2 | apple | App |
| 2 | apple | Aps |
| 2 | apple | Apl |
| 2 | apple | Ale |
| 2 | apple | Apls |

I need to do this in insert statement and if the id already has the name and desc I don’t need to add the just to avoid duplications.

I tired this Sql :

```sql
Select distinct a.id,a.name,a.desc
From table a cross join table b
Where a.name = b.name
```

I got the permutations but I want to remove the ones I don’t need. Also I want to do it in insert select, I am doing a distinct not sure how I can do that.

Comment: You reference a `table2` in your SQL, but you only include one table's definition in your question. Also why `Where table.name = table.name`? The only time that will *not* be TRUE is when `table.name` has the value `NULL` (as `NULL` doesn't equal itself). As such, why not just `table.name IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Oh assume that table and table2 are both same tables as I mentioned earlier

Comment: Then don't give them different names in your SQL, that's confusing. Alias them instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like what you are after from the sample data and expected results. I use a couple of derived tables to get the `DISTINCT` combinations of `Id` & `Name`, and `Name` & `Desc`, and `JOIN` on the `Name`:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO dbo.YourTable
FROM (VALUES(1,'apple','App'),
            (1,'apple','Aps'),
            (2,'apple','Apl'),
            (2,'apple','Ale'),
            (2,'apple','Apls'),
            (3,'orange','orng'))V(Id,Name,[desc]); --DESC is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for names

GO

SELECT NI.Id,
       ND.Name,
       ND.[desc]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
             Name,
             [Desc]
      FROM dbo.YourTable) ND
     JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                  Id,
                  Name
           FROM dbo.YourTable) NI ON ND.Name = NI.Name
WHERE NI.Name = 'apple';
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: One thing though, it is adding the value which is already there for instance if the 1 has though 2 values it shouldn’t add it but in this case it is adding it .

Comment: I don't follow what you are stating there, @RR8422 . The results in the above and the expected results in your question are the same, with 10 rows returned.